# Vector Bearing Force Application.

Tags: trigonometry

We have this question, for a simple exercice.

A Force of $125N$ acts on an object. Another force of 85N acts on the same object an an angle of $72 ^\circ $from the first force find the magnitude of the resultant force!

Ok so i did this:

```
          85N
      __________
     /         /
    /         /
125/         / 125N
  /         /
 /_________/
  85N
```

And then drew like a line conecting the lower left vertice to upper right vertice.. that was $72 ^\circ $ . Well after that i was finding the magnitude of resultant force so i did this:

> $$\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 -2ab * cos(C)}$$

Then ofcourse after i substituted 125 for A, then 85 for B, and C for $72 ^\circ $

I got

$127.606N$ Well aparently i think i got this wrong because [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160507113203AAfOJtc) anwser says otherwise. did i do something wrong here? Help would be appreciated!

Edit my picture:

[image]

I dont understand why we have to do $180^\circ-72^\circ = 108^\circ$ then calculate with $108^\circ$

Comment: You calculated the difference between the forces. Look at your diagram. You want $180^{\circ}-72^{\circ}=108^{circ}$.

Comment: Your suppose to decrease 180? Why @JohnDouma Very confused here!!?Its the right anwser but why??

Comment: Look at your diagram. Using $72^{\circ}$ you calculate $125N-85N$. The head to tail summation gives you the lower $85N$ vector plus the $125N$ vector on the right hand side of your diagram. Place arrows on your vectors and you may see it more clearly.

Comment: Huh @JohnDouma let me take a picture of my diagram.. ill probably understand better then

Comment: You're using the Law of Cosines to solve this problem. But what the Law of Cosines is giving you is the length of the *other* diagonal. That is, it's giving you the length of the line from the top left to the bottom right.

Comment: Your parallelogram has two diagonals. Which one should be the sum?

Comment: @JohnDouma sorry for the lateness i had to go to the supermarket.. but i updated picture

Comment: @pyrazolam isnt it giving the resultant vector? Can you see my picture if im on the correct path?

Comment: Your resultant vector is correct. Now do you see why $72^{\circ}$ is not the correct angle?

Comment: No Lol. @JohnDouma this is what i had before.. and i still dont understand why its not $72 ^\circ$ . sorry for bieng slow...

Comment: Is the angle opposite $\vec{x}$ less than or greater than $90^{\circ}$?

Comment: Its less than 90.... because its the same as its opposite angle $72 ^\circ$

Comment: I dont understand this @JohnDouma Please help! I need to understand this for my test tuesday!